# how can i use the number from textfield of each row in listview and make a call on this number?

Tags: android, listview

here is my custom adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    ImageView myImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView myNames= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    TextView myNumbers= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contact_num);
    Button btn= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.caller_button);
    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myNames.setText(nameArray[position]);
    myNumbers.setText(numberArray[position]);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear :'(

Comment: you already have position for each row to detect so you can make a call any item for the specified position.

Comment: i created a listview, there each row contains a name,a phone number and a button. i want to make call on that number by pressing the button.

Comment: so here is your number call it inside your onClick(): "numberArray[position]"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ListView listView;
   ...
   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      this.listView = (ListView) viewGroup;
```

and then in each `View.OnClickListener` I can get the position of the clicked item by

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   ...
   MyAdapter.this.listView.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent()));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in adapter getView method:

```
yourViewHolder.callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(View view){

String callNum=yourViewHolder.textField.getText().toString();
String callUri="tel:"+callNum;
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(callUri));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
);
```