# How to send ID from an Element on listItems to another View where i wana publish all information of this Element?

Tags: android

This ListView class where i bring different element from my server with help of php and JSON calls to my listview. The problem is i would like to send the ID of element to another view when i click of specific element on listview. and in another View i would like to publish the detail information about the element that i clicked. Any wan have idea about that?

```
public class Forestillinger extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView dagensaktivitet;
TextView txt;
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject hc = null;
JSONArray fstilling;
public String hk = "";
int success;
String msg;
final Context c = this;
StableArrayAdapter adb;
private static final String url_Forestillinger = "http://barnestasjonen.no/test/db_get_forestillinger.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forestillinger);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    dagensaktivitet = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.forestillinglist);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems) {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return view;
        }
    };
    dagensaktivitet.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("i oncreate", adapter.toString());

    //if(!fromLocalDB())
    try {
        new getShows().execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //JSONObject tickets = task.getJSon();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dagensaktivitet.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Forestilling.class);
            i.putExtra("selectedItem", listItems.get(position));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

public void fromExtDB() throws JSONException {
    fstilling = hc.getJSONArray("forestillinger");
    for (int i = 0; i < fstilling.length(); i++) {
        listItems.add(fstilling.getJSONObject(i).getString("tittel")+fstilling.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_forestillinger, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void forestillingResult(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Forestillinger.this)
            .setTitle("OBS!!!")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    hk = "";
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<Integer> trialId;

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, List<Integer> objectId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        trialId = objectId;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    public int getActualId(int position)
    {
        return trialId.get(position);
    }
}
class getShows extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("TEST", "jeg er her");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "adam@gmail.com"));
        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "android"));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Forestillinger, "POST", params);

        try {
            if (json != null) {
                success = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("success"));
                msg = json.toString();
                System.out.println("Vi er her:" + msg + "   " + success);

            }

            if (success == 1) {
                hc = json;
                System.out.println("jojo"+json.toString());

            }
            else
            {

                msg=json.getString("message");
                System.out.println(msg);
                msg= Html.fromHtml(msg).toString();
                hk = msg;

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //run code
        try {
            Log.d("TAG23", "vi er in onpostExecute");
            if(success == 1) {
                fromExtDB();
            }else{
                forestillingResult();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

and here is the second view.

```
public class Forestilling extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forestilling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /*Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.d("TAG:", "" + extras.getInt("TryThis"));*/
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = extras.getString("selectedItem");

    Log.d("TAG:", "" + s);


    TextView tit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tittel);
    TextView dato = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dato);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_forestilling, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to flag at this moment, but this might be a duplicate of [how can i use the number from textfield of each row in listview and make a call on this number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535401/how-can-i-use-the-number-from-textfield-of-each-row-in-listview-and-make-a-call/36535599#36535599)

Anyway, my answer given there might solve your problem:

Here is what I do:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ListView listView;
   ...
   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      this.listView = (ListView) viewGroup;
```

and then in each `View.OnClickListener` I can get the position of the clicked item by

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   ...
   MyAdapter.this.listView.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent()));
```

Comment: Can you please pulish the code? i know what is the logic back the problem but i can not fix that :(